# "Enter a market" vs. "break into a market"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs, collocation

Could you please shed light on the difference, if any, between "enter" vs. "break into" a market? Are they synonyms and interchangeable, or does the latter of the two imply more force?

Answer (score 1):

My intuition is that *enter* is used more often after the event (‘They entered the market at a very good time') and that *break into* is used more often before the event (‘They’re trying to break into the market, but they’re not having a lot of luck’). This, however, would need to be tested by a detailed corpus search.

Comment: I think that 'break into' connotes some measure of success in the market, also.

Answer (score 1):

The relative difficulty in becoming a successful participant in a given market is often described in terms of *[barriers to entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barriers_to_entry)*.

If the barriers are fairly low (e.g., no significant capital investment, no market leader to overcome, no patent or trade secret obstacles), one can **enter** a market fairly easily.

If the barriers are high (a need to overcome the aforementioned challenges), one's efforts must be more aggressive and one needs to **break into** that market.

Notwithstanding the common coupling of *breaking and entering*, in market terms, the distinction has to do with the degree of difficulty of attainment.

Answer (score 0):

Talking economically means that the latter is not forceful - instead, it symbolizes a breakthrough (and the two are interchangeable in this context). However, in common spoken English, "break into" usually represents force, in the sense of some sort of thieving. "Enter" a market in common spoken English represents walking into a market.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I've heard them used mostly interchangeably. "Break" is the more colorful way of saying it - it comes with the connotation that entrance to the industry was difficult.